# Modal always re-rendering when typing in input for React-Bootstrap-Table2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to implement an 'Edit Category' modal that can edit the current selected row in React-Bootstrap-Table2.

However, when I tried to type in Category Description, it always re-renders the modal and I can only type 1 letter at a time.

Also, how can I set the value of the state for both the inputs based on the selected row's info because currently if I set the value of Category Name with `modalInfo.categoryName`, then the input cannot be edited.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-margulis-oki0x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The ModalContent component should have its own state that controls the value of its input; you should setCategoryName only when the user submits the modal. As it is now, every input change will try and setCategoryName, which will rerender the whole app.

Comment: You don't have css because you need to `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in your index.js file per the [React-Bootstrap docs.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css)

Comment: So what you meant is I should change or remove my current onChange method for my input field?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure if I understood your explanation correctly so I've tried another method which is separating the ModalContent into another individual component (creating a new file called ModalContent.js) and importing it into my current page which has the Bootstrap Table. Then I passed the selected row's info into ModalContent.js when onClick and now I can edit without the modal re-rendering repeatedly! 

Maybe you can let me know if this is a good/correct way to do it or not.